# Why is my Povidone-Iodine 10% Solution losing it's color which disappeared, 2 tsp mixed with 6 oz distilled water, sitting out for 3 days?

Tags: solutions

I was directed to use this method of 2 tsp povidone mixed with 6 oz distilled water for mouth gargling, and also either using the mixed solution in a neti pot on the nose, or using the mixed solution in a spray bottle on the nose.
?1.  I do not know if I should have added salt to make simple saline out of the distilled water.
?2.  The bright brown color disappeared in an open measuring cup mixture of distilled water + povidone after sitting out uncovered on the counter for 2 or 3 days.  Do I have to have a lid on the mixture?  Or do I need to create smaller portions of the mixture so I only prepare what I need in each treatment for only one treatment at a time? And all the original povidone needs to stay in the original bottle unless needed for one specific treatment at a time?  Thank you.

Comment: Be aware  that personal medical advices are explicitly off-topic on chemistry SE site. Users may address chemical aspects, but will avoid any medical context. It is also possible the question will be closed due its medical relation. It is best to ask about in a pharmacy or at a pharmacologist.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [site](https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/3018/smpc#gref)

> Povidone iodine is inactivated or becomes unstable in the presence of sodium thiosulphate, heat, light or alkaline pH. Once opened – use immediately. Discard immediately after first use.

Note the instability to light. Do not store this open-topped or in a clear glass bottle. You will need to make up your gargle solution fresh each time.

Comment: Protection of the product against day light is *the* reason why these bottles including iodine solutions are either stored in containers of dark brown glass, or of at least dark and opaque plastic ([example](https://3spharmacy.com.np/product/ixod-betadine-solution-500ml-bs500-zmc4)).

Answer (score 1):

An iodine solution gets discolored if left uncovered after more than one day. And there are at least two reasons : 1) Iodine is slightly volatile and slowly evaporates from any aqueous solution (but this is not the main reason). 2) The French chemist Louis Pasteur has shown in $1880$ that air contains plenty of organic spores, pollen, dust, bacteria and pathogenic agents that are continuously falling down on any aqueous surface, slowly producing polluted water. All this organic material has reducing properties : it will soon reduce brown $\ce{I2}$ to colorless iodide ions $\ce{I-}$. Two or three days is enough to discolor your solution.